# Redirect end of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all pages ending in ...-black-and-white/ to pages without the -black-and-white/.

For example: /peace-tattoos-for-girls/30-artistic-chinese-tattoo-symbols-black-and-white/ to /peace-tattoos-for-girls/30-artistic-chinese-tattoo-symbols/

There are over 30k pages like this, how do I do this through .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule (.*)-black-and-white/$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, however, when I go to /peace-tattoos-for-girls/30-artistic-chinese-tattoo-symbols-black-and-white/ I end up at /peace-tattoos-for-girls/. ANy reason for that?

Comment: You have to change your destination page name the same way as with your redirect...

Comment: Ok, I am not sure what you mean. Check this link out [link](http://tattoomagz.com/spine-tattoos-for-women/flickr-the-got-your-back-tattoos-on-women-only-pool/) It used to have /spine-tattoos-for-women/flickr-the-got-your-back-tattoos-on-women-only-pool-black-and-while but I removed all pages. Now after redirect if I enter /spine-tattoos-for-women/flickr-the-got-your-back-tattoos-on-women-only-pool-black-and-while I get to /spine-tattoos-for-women/ but not /spine-tattoos-for-women/flickr-the-got-your-back-tattoos-on-women-only-pool/. Can you please clarify what am I doing wrong here?